# java web application to intercept all message on server

Tags: java, tomcat

Is it possible to deploy a java web application on a server which will listen and intercept all message request/response on server? write it on a og file for example!
For example, If I have some application which produce some request and the the server response and the java app will write these exchange to a log file independently of the server writing log file service.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Do you have some recommendation with how to do that?

Comment: @AKSW, how we can do that